# Aligning different elements inside div in html

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am new to php.

And i am using following code to show a form

```
<div class="wrapperReg">

        <div id="searchContainer" style="display: inline; margin-top: 20px">
          <form>
             <label class="ringSetName" style="font-size: 16pt;" >Firstname</label>
             <input id="nameBox" style="width:250px; margin-top:10px; margin-left: 30px; height:30px;" name="q" type="text"/>         
          </form>
       </div>

       <div id="searchContainer" style="display: inline; margin-top: 20px">
          <form>
             <label class="ringSetName" style="font-size: 16pt;" >Lastname</label>
             <input id="nameBox" style="width:250px; margin-top:10px; margin-left: 30px; height:30px;" name="q" type="text"/>         
          </form>
       </div>

       <div id="searchContainer" style="display: inline; margin-top: 20px">
          <form>
             <label class="ringSetName" style="font-size: 16pt;" >Email</label>
             <input id="nameBox" style="width:250px; margin-top:10px; margin-left:30px; height:30px;" name="q" type="text"/>          
          </form>
       </div>

       <div id="searchContainer" style="display: inline; margin-top: 20px">
          <form>
             <label class="ringSetName" style="font-size: 16pt;" >Phone</label>
             <input id="nameBox" style="width:250px; margin-top:10px; margin-left: 30px; height:30px;" name="q" type="text"/>         
          </form>
       </div>

     <div class="submit" style="display: inline;" style="margin-top: 10px">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit-text"/>
     </div>
```

CSS is as follow

```
.wrapperReg{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}
```

It is showing stuff as below

[image: enter code here]

How can i align so that all the elements are aligned horizontally inside the main div and The Text should be base aligned and also the Input fileds be vertically aligned to each.

Also Need to place the submit button aligned horizontally too.

Comment: Well, you COULD use tables, however this might not be the best solution =/

Comment: you only need one `<form></form>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using float?

```
label{float: left;}
label + input{float: right;}
```

And add overflow:hidden to your `form`. And wrap your form elements in one form.

Comment: this is working however label and input are not inline. Label is at top and input is below

Answer (score 0):

```
label {float: left; width: 200px; clear: left}
label + input {float: left; width: 150px}
```

ID should be unique in whole document, use class for searchContainer.

Comment: COPY paste stuff, will fix it . I am not sure how to implement what you wrote